# How to change from an int to a string based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I have a data frame with a list of names and their gender. The default data frame has either a "0" or a "1" in the gender column for each name of the person in which the "0" implies that the person is a male while the "1" implies that the person is a female. How do I change the zeros and the ones in the gender column to males and females?

Comment: A simple `if` statement should do it.

Comment: Use `df.where()`

Comment: I get the idea but I'm looking for the specific code to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
df['gender'] = df['gender'].map({1:'female', 0:'male'})
```

OR

```
df.loc[(df.gender == 0), 'gender'] = 'male'
df.loc[(df.gender == 1), 'gender'] = 'female'
```

Comment: Just saw your edit. Much nice on one line

Answer (score 0):

Direct indexing:

```
df['gender'] = np.array(['male', 'female'])[df.gender]
```